# flask-sqlalchemy: joined tables and one result object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am coming from a python-django and am trying to get a grasp on flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)


class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'), nullable=False)
```

I want to get a joined result list:

```
results = Book.query.filter(Author.name=='tom')

for result in results:
  print(result.title, result.???.name)
```

How do I access the fields of the joined tables?

Comment: result.author.name?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'), nullable=False)
    author = relationship("Author")
```

I needed to add the line

```
author = relationship("Author")
```

to the model. It seems to be necessary to declare the relationship on the object level. I did miss this.

Now the line can be:

```
print(result.title, result.author.name)
```